# Creating a Flowable equivliant with Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to migrate my Android App from RxJava to Kotlin Coroutines.

One thing I'm using is a `Flowable` (Or `Observable`) for my **Room Database**, in my `getAll()` method that gets all the notes in my database and updates the adapter.

In **Room**, if such method returns a `Flowable`, the subscribe callback will be called everytime the data changes (insert, update, delete).

What is the equivalent of such a method in Kotlin Coroutines? As I understand, a coroutine job is a one time job, and when it's over, that's it, unless you want to repeat it at a fixed rate.

Comment: Eventually, [the equivalent is a `Flow`](https://medium.com/@elizarov/reactive-streams-and-kotlin-flows-bfd12772cda4). Right now, flows are an experimental API.

Answer (score 0):

There was already a suggested answer about `Coroutine Flow`, which is still an experimental feature. I personally prefer using `coroutines` together with `LiveData` which is especially helpful in your case when you will use the data to update adapters or other UI components. Fetch data with `coroutines`, update `LiveData` object in ViewModel and subscribe to that object in your Fragment etc.